# Design Pattern Adapter in C

Tags: c, adapter

**Definition**:

> Adapter is a structural design pattern that allows objects with
> incompatible interfaces to collaborate.

I have to use incompatible callback function pointers with a difference in the first parameter.

We know objects have key-value pairs, and arrays have index-value pairs. char * vs int.

```
void object_callback(char *key, void *value) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", index, value);
}

void array_callback(int index, void *value) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", index, value);
}
```

**Use Case**

```
void process_object(void (*callback)(char *key, void *value)) {
    // callback if key-value-based properties
    callback(key, value);

    // callback for array-based properties
    callback((int)key, value); // trying to implement adapter pattern for this
}
```

I could have used `void *` but looking for an elegant solution based on Adapter Design Pattern.

**My Attempt**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Adapter {
    void (*obj)(char *key, void *value);
    void (*arr)(int index, void *value);
} Adapter;

void property_callback(char *key, void *value) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", key, value);
}

void array_callback(int index, void *value) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", index, value);
}
```

Comment: It isn't quite clear what your problem is. Can you show how you use your callbacks and how you want to use them?

Comment: How does `object_callback` make any sense? What is `index` in that function?

Comment: index is the index of the item in the array

Comment: What array? There is no array in your code. And what I asked was how `object_callback` knows the meaning of `index`, is it a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an adapter function that will bridge the gap between the two different callback interfaces. Here is a simple example of using adapter functions with different callbacks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Define the original callback functions
void objectCallback(char *key, void *value) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", key, (char*)value);
}

void arrayCallback(int index, void *value) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", index, (char*)value);
}

// Adapter structure to encapsulate the original callbacks
typedef struct {
    void (*callback)(void* keyOrIndex, void *value);
} Adapter;

// Adapter function for objectCallback
void objectAdapter(void* key, void *value) {
    objectCallback((char*)key, value);
}

// Adapter function for arrayCallback
void arrayAdapter(void* key, void *value) {
    int idx = (int)(long)key; // Cast void pointer to int
    arrayCallback(idx, value);
}

int main() {
    // Create an adapter for objectCallback
    Adapter objectAdapterInstance = {objectAdapter};

    // Create an adapter for arrayCallback
    Adapter arrayAdapterInstance = {arrayAdapter};

    // Demonstrate the use of the adapters
    char* k = "property_key";
    char* v = "property_value";

    // Use the object adapter
    objectAdapterInstance.callback(k, v);

    // Use the array adapter
    int i = 123;
    arrayAdapterInstance.callback((void*)(long)i, v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I realize the best approach would be to have a single method with `void *`, check if `isdigit` is to call the array version, and if not, call the other object version.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no `void*` for the first parameter, then you can simply use that one to distinguish between the two uses, during compile-time:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void object_callback(char *key, void *value) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", key, (char*)value);
}

void array_callback(int index, void *value) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", index, (char*)value);
}


#define callback(a, b)                \
  _Generic((a),                       \
           char*:  object_callback,   \
           int:    array_callback     \
          ) (a,b)


int main (void)
{
    callback("hello", "world");
    callback(123, "world");
}
```

Comment: A general note here is that avoiding function pointers generally leads to faster code. A solution with function pointers wouldn't likely get inlined by the compiler, meaning overhead execution time. Whereas my code above gets easily boiled down to two printf calls by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

Solution 1: remove argument list for callback function pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void property_callback(char *key, void *value) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", key, (char*)value);
}

void array_callback(int index, void *value) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", index, (char*)value);
}

void process_object( void (*callback)(),
    int functype, char *key, int index, void *value) 
{
    if(functype==1) callback(key, value);
    if(functype==2) callback(index, value);
}

int main()
{
    process_object(property_callback , 1, "key", 123 , "value" ); 
    process_object(array_callback    , 2, "key", 123 , "value" );  
    return 0;
}
```

Solution 2: Use a union of callback pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void property_callback(char *key, void *value) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", key, (char*)value);
}

void array_callback(int index, void *value) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", index, (char*)value);
}

typedef union {
    void (*prop)(char *key, void *value); 
    void (*arr)(int index, void *value);
} cbtype;

void process_object( cbtype callback,
    int functype, char *key, int index, void *value) 
{
    if(functype==1) callback.prop(key, value);
    if(functype==2) callback.arr(index, value);
}

int main()
{
    process_object( (cbtype){.prop=property_callback} , 1, "key", 123 , "value" ); 
    process_object( (cbtype){.arr=array_callback}     , 2, "key", 123 , "value" );  
    return 0;
}
```